# i have data in my shopify api i want to use that data in my reactjs app how do i do that

Tags: html, css, reactjs, api, shopify

data is like this
i just want to show title and ratings in a list thats all
api is like this = {apikey}{password}@{shopname}.myshopify/admin/api/{api-version}/{resource.json}

```
{ 
  "orders": [
              { "tittle" : "name 1", "rating": 5 }, 
              { "tittle" : "name 2", "rating": 3 }, 
              { "tittle" : "name 3", "rating": 1 }, 
              { "tittle" : "name 4", "rating": 2 }, 
           ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming you are making a request to the api, since you didnt gave almost nothing of information.

const [orders, setOrders] = useState();

ApiRequest.then((res) => setOrders(res.orders)) (**create a state for your api response**)

```js
<ul>
 {orders.map((order) => <li> Title: {order.title}, Rating: {order.rating} </li>)}
</ul>
```

Render the response into the JSX by mapping the result array.

Comment: Yes thanks but i wanted to know can i fetch data from shopifys admin api in react js because i have that admin api but i am not able fetch data from that

Comment: First you need to see if the endpoint actually exists and can be used. Use postman and try it..